# Slow NodeJS upstart time with buildroot, but fast with raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux, node.js, buildroot

Building a small linux distro with buildroot using the raspberrypi_defconfig + nodeJS i get a 12+ second upstart on every single node file i try to run.

If i on the other hand try it out in raspbian, it takes less than 2 seconds.

Does this have anything to do with the way the kernel is being compiled/missing packages/flags i need to run stuff with?

Thanks!